# node_exporter cpu collector failed

Tags: prometheus

I start a node_exporter on a centOs.
it's log:

`ERRO[0013] ERROR: cpu collector failed after 0.006487s: open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: no such file or directory  source="collector.go:132"`

what's the problem?

Comment: What kernel version are u running on ( `uname -a` ) and what is the version of the node exporter?

Comment: @yamenk    


[root@IST-Slave5 ~]# uname -a.  
Linux IST-Slave5 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: node_exporter-0.16.0.linux-amd64